# Can't open video stream from Android native code with cv::VideoCapture

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, ar.drone

I'm using Opencv with Android NDK and I'd like to open my AR.Drone video stream.
I saw it is possible with the code

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
if (!cap.open("tcp://192.168.1.1:5555"))
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "VIDEO:", "can't open stream : %s", strerror(errno));
}
```

But I get the error "VIDEO: can't open stream : Success"

I tried with the default Android camera (0) and a local file ("/sdcard/DCIM/myvideo.mp4") but I keep getting the same error...

Any Idea?

Comment: sorry dear, that code will work on a PC, but not on android, since there's no backend there to decompress it (ffmpeg/gstreamer). so you can neither open a videofile, nor a webstream

Comment: Build FFmpeg and use AVutils to decode videos.

Comment: I won't lose my time with that anymore thanks to you guys !! Thank you very much !